# What object calls the constructor?

Tags: java

```
Point point = new Point (30, 20);
```

`Point(int, int)` here is a constructor of the Point class, it is by default not private and not static, so a Point object needs to be calling it, but above it is not being called as a method of a Point object, but instead by the `new` operator. What does the `new` operator do other than allocating memory? Does it automatically create an empty Point object and then call the constructor as a method of this Point object? So if I make the constructor private does it mean the`new` operator won't work anywhere else except inside the class?

Comment: maybe this can lighten you up or guide you: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html

Comment: We cannot create an object without invoking a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens at runtime when invoking a constructor is defined in [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4). Here's a partial quote:

> Next, space is allocated for the new class instance. If there is insufficient space to allocate the object, evaluation of the class instance creation expression completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError.
>
> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified class type and all its superclasses. As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).
>
> Next, the actual arguments to the constructor are evaluated, left-to-right. If any of the argument evaluations completes abruptly, any argument expressions to its right are not evaluated, and the class instance creation expression completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> Next, the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked. This results in invoking at least one constructor for each superclass of the class type. This process can be directed by explicit constructor invocation statements (§8.8) and is specified in detail in §12.5.
>
> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

And indeed, if the constructor is private, it won't be usable outside of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is not a method.

Memory allocation takes place after the constructor is called.

We use new keyword(mostly) to create objects of a class.

When we create an object of a class by new, it calls the right constructor based upon the signature.

To answer your question :

1. JVM called the constructor.
2. If you make the constructor private, you can not create object of that class outside that class, so right, new operator won't work outside that class.

Comment: memory allocation does not take place after the constructor is called, just read the answer given above

Comment: Everything happens after the constructor is called.
This might help
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html

Comment: okay you your own link says that first memory is allocated, how can you initialize initial default values / or any call constructor, before there is any memory allocated to store those values, don't answer questions you don't know the answer to.

Comment: `At the beginning of an object's life, the Java virtual machine (JVM) allocates enough memory on the heap to accommodate the object's instance variables. When you allocate memory for a new object with the new operator or the newInstance() method of class Class, the Java virtual machine will insure that initialization code is run before you can use the newly-allocated memory.` So essentially what happens in order is **JVM allocates memory, it initializes every variable, then allows you to use the object**. Therefore, constructor is called AFTER allocation.